# Multi Language DjangoCMS

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, django-cms

I want use multi language in my project . I had install cms app core . But this app only English language.
But I want multi language when I choose option . So I have to create anorther app or create new template or anything ? . I don't know how to do it . Let me know the solution

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create different apps for multi languages. To use that, type this in your settings.py

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

LANGUAGES = [
    ('de', _('German')),
    ('en', _('English')),
]
```

you can use as much languages as you want.

Comment: so i have to another app like cms app core with different language ?

Comment: I had use i18n to trans my admin page and toolbarcms but some word not trans . I use {% 
 trans "Word" %} . I think need .po file but i dont know where and how to import that file